# Can I write PHP inside JavaScript inside PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Inside a PHP script I have this:

```
echo <<<EOD

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('my_element_id').innerHTML='Do stuff';
</script>

EOD;
```

Can I add PHP inside the JavaScript? Replace the "Do stuff" part with PHP code? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Yes you can do it... and before asking try to implement that thing..:)

Comment: If you add it in using PHP tags it will run at page serving time. If you want it to run at some point during the use of the page (e.g. in response to a click) you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: You surely can do it...

Comment: ......d').innerHTML='<?php echo "I am PHP" ?>';

Comment: can you try this document.getElementById('my_element_id').innerHTML='<?php code goes here ?>';  ?

Comment: Thank you all, working on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it should be noted that this has nothing to do with javascript. You could have *any* form of text. Your actual question is how to use a variable inside of a heredoc.

[Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) is defined as the following:

> **Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings**. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc. The construct is ideal for embedding PHP code or other large blocks of text without the need for escaping.

Meaning that since this works:

```
$name = 'Foo';

echo "My name is $name"; // Using double quotes so variables get expanded
```

Then this also works:

```
$name = 'Foo';

echo <<<EOD
    My name is <strong>$name</strong>
EOD;  // Using heredoc so variables get expanded
```

Essentially meaning that yes, as long as you put your `'Do stuff'` content into a variable first. Note that if you use more advanced variables/arrays, it's a good idea to do a `$array = json_encode($array)` before pasting it into JS code (imagine if `$name` was `The Boss's Wife` - then the apostrophe would ruin your JS if you don't encode it).

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/201515)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like:

```
<?php 
$anyphpvariable='foo';
echo <<<EOD 
    <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById('my_element_id').innerHTML=$anyphpvariable;

    </script>
EOD;
?>
```

Anything from php can be assign to JS and its good practice.
But not JS can assign anything to PHP.

Comment: That's going to throw a Reference error because `foo` is not defined as a JavaScript variable.

Comment: surround $anyphpvariable with quotes like ...erHTML='$anyphpvariable';

Comment: Providing `$anyphpvariable` contains no new lines or `'` characters (which it doesn't in this example, but that isn't a robust solution). @h2ooooooo's answer covers this and is much better.

Comment: Yes thats better for sure. why did you not accept @h2ooooooo's answer?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, but I can only get what you want if I place the code after the relevant HTML. You can echo scripts...for example, this will work:

```
<div id="footer">Hey</div>
<?php 
$myVar = 'Hello';
echo "<SCRIPT>
   document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = '$myVar';
</SCRIPT>";
?> // You will see Hello in the footer
```

but this will not work:

```
<?php 
$myVar = 'Hello';
echo "<SCRIPT>
   document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = '$myVar';
</SCRIPT>";
?>
<div id="footer">Hey</div>// You will see Hey in the footer
```

As a side note, these other functions/methods will work too:

```
$myVar = 'Hi';
echo "<SCRIPT>
    alert('$myVar');
</SCRIPT>";//Alerts 'Hi'

$myVar = 'home.php';
echo "<SCRIPT>
    location = '$myVar';
</SCRIPT>";//Takes you to home.php

$myVar = 'hi';
echo "<SCRIPT>
    myFunction('$myVar');
</SCRIPT>";//calls myFunction with argument $myVar
```